# Second async function running before first async is finished

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to write tests for a node/postgresSQL setup. Currently at the step where I create a table and then seed the table with users. I have an async function called createUserTable and then a second async function called seedUserTable, but when I run them I get the error 'relation "public.user" does not exist. I'm really confused as to why my second async function is running before the first one has finished.

Here is my code

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const { DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_PORT, DB_TEST_DATABASE } = require('./config');

const pool = new Pool({
    host: DB_HOST,
    port: DB_PORT,
    user: DB_USERNAME,
    password: DB_PASSWORD,
    database: DB_TEST_DATABASE,
});

const createUserTable = async () => {
    console.log('createUserTable')
    try {
        const newUserTable = await pool.query(`
            CREATE TABLE public.user
            (
                user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                username VARCHAR(35) UNIQUE NOT NULL
            );
        `);
        console.log(newUserTable);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
}

const seedUserTable = async () => {
    console.log('seedUserTable')
    try {
        const seedUserTable = await pool.query(`
            INSERT INTO public.user(username)
                VALUES (
                        $1
                    ),
                    (
                        $2
                    )
                    RETURNING *
        `,
            [
                'demo',
                'demo2',
            ]
        );
        console.log(seedUserTable);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }

}

createUserTable();
seedUserTable();
```

This is what I'm getting in the terminal.

```
$ node index2.js
createUserTable
seedUserTable
relation "public.user" does not exist
Result {
  command: 'CREATE',
  rowCount: null,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: undefined,
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object],
      builtins: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false
}
```

Edit: Removed the async from the two functions and wrapped the call in an async function like this.

```
(async () => {
    await createUserTable();
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('5000 ms timeout');
    }, 5000);
    await seedUserTable();
})();
```

Currently getting this error:

```
createUserTable
Promise { <pending> }
seedUserTable
Promise { <pending> }
(node:19684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: relation "public.user" does not exist
5000 ms timeout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to remove all async functions that you've added and do this down below:

```
(async() => {

    await createUserTable();
    await seedUserTable();
    
})();
```

Comment: I gave that a shot and it's running a little better in order, but it seems that the next function is still running before the promise is finished. This is what I got in the terminal.

`
$ node index2.js
createUserTable
Promise { <pending> }
seedUserTable
Promise { <pending> }
(node:16276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: relation "public.user" does not exist
`

Comment: Ok try adding setTimeout() before seedUserTable function with 5 seconds at least just to make sure that the problem isn't caused by the async function.

Comment: Okay, gave that a try, but the timeout finishes after the two async functions return a pending promise. Edited the main post ot make it more clear what I did and what errors I'm getting back.

Comment: put await seedUserTable(); inside the timeout function.

Comment: Oh dang, thanks for the correction on how to use the timeout function. That did the trick! Thanks Yaser!

Answer (score 0):

i am just thinking that the problem maybe from the postgress naming when it creates tables
try checking the name of the tables in the database after it's creation

Comment: Went ahead and checked the table that was created and the table name is ''user". If I disabled my first function "createUserTable" after getting the error 'Relation "public.user" does not exist' and run the file, the "seedUserTable" function works correctly.